# Large space between text in table where image has rowspan in HTML

Tags: html, html-table

I have text and picture in table:

```
<table>
       <tr><td>Jon Kowalsky</td>
       <td rowspan="4"><img src="forrest.jpg"  height="150px"/></td></tr>
       <tr><td>Eagle Rock Ave</td></tr>
       <tr><td>New York</td></tr>
       <tr><td><a href="mailto:ja@jankowalski.pl">ja@jankowalski</a></td></tr>
</table>
```

as you can see picture is in all four rows but it makes large spaces between text [picture below].

[image: Example picture]

Can I keep text and image in table and make spaces between text smaller?

Comment: Please don't use table for layout purpose, we are in 2018. Your table cells on the left are all tall one quarter of your cell on the right, so you see white space. If you add a border you'll see what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have a fixed `height` for the image, the table row height does not change much. Either reduce the `height` of the image or increase `rowspan` of the table cell of the image and set the `line-height` of `td` to a lower value or 0.

```
<table>
       <tr><td>Jon Kowalsky</td>
       <td rowspan="6"><img src="forrest.jpg"  height="150px"/></td></tr>
       <tr><td>Eagle Rock Ave</td></tr>
       <tr><td>New York</td></tr>
       <tr><td><a href="mailto:ja@jankowalski.pl">ja@jankowalski</a></td></tr>
       <tr></tr>
       <tr></tr>
</table>
```

And the css

```
td{
    line-height: 0; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What is happening is that the text in the cells to the left will span the entire height of the cell with the picture occupying the specified amount of rows.

A possible solution is to use other html elements with a bit of CSS.

For example:

```
<div class="details">
    <p>Jon Kowalsky</p>
    <p>Eagle Rock Ave</p>
    <p>New York</p>
    <p><a href="mailto:ja@jankowalski.pl">ja@jankowalski</a></p>
</div>
<img src="forrest.jpg"  height="150px"/></td>

<style>
.details {
    float: left;
}

.details p:first-child {
    margin-top: 20px;
}

.details p {
    margin: 0;
}
</style>
```